Is a vapor barrier really necessary in crawl spaces in dryer areas (Colorado)?
We're looking at putting an offer in on a home in Northern Colorado. However, the home has had foundation work in the past and has notes on previous work that installing a vapor barrier to the crawl space was discussed at the time the bracing work was done, but the owners did not choose to install one at that time. The idea of any foundation work is overwhelming, and we're not sure if this vapor barrier is necessary (home was built in the 50s and has made it this far with out one?). How can we determine if this is a necessary installation or just another way for the company doing the foundation work to earn a little more on the job?

Vapour barrier should be the cheapest job.  It is a roll of poly plastic that you can install yourself(works better with two people, one to unroll and one to use the staple gun).  Probably two or three days of starbucks coffee for two.
